# understanding [x:y] structure in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector

I'm not sure whether I've understood the following code correctly:

```
i1=[0:M-1];
c_ind(i1+1)=i1+1;
i1=[0:M-1];
d_ind(i1+1)=i1+1;
```

Am I right assuming that this code snippet produces two vectors *c_ind* and *d_ind* which both contain the numbers 1, 2, 3, ..., M ?

Thanks a lot for your appreciated help - being not sure about this makes progressing hard ;)

Best 
- astriffe

Comment: Is there anything stopping you firing up MATLAB (or Octave, the free equivalent) and just *testing* this?

Comment: I don't have MATLAB installed here and I thought it was really easy for someone who knows MATLAB... but maybe I should get Octave - thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output of Octave for this code below. Yes, it does produce two vectors, `c_ind` and `d_ind`, both counting up from `1` to `M`.

I have no idea why this was written this way.

```
>> M = 4
M =  4
>> i1=[0:M-1]
    c_ind(i1+1)=i1+1
    i1=[0:M-1]
    d_ind(i1+1)=i1+1
i1 =

        0        1        2        3

>> c_ind =

        1        2        3        4

>> i1 =

        0        1        2        3

>> d_ind =

        1        2        3        4
```

The reason why this actually works is because the syntax `array([indices]) = [values]` maps the list of `values` onto the locations specified by `indices`.

```
>> myvec2([1,4,7]) = [10,20,30]
myvec2 =

       10        0        0       20        0        0       30

>> myvec(5:7) = [10,20,30]
myvec =

        0        0        0        0       10       20       30
```

Comment: And also Matlab starts indexing from 1 unlike many languages, hence if you try c_ind(i1) you should get an error as it will try c_ind(0) which is not allowed in Matlab.